# CID Image generation issue over HTTPS

Tags: contextual-image-delivery

**Below mentioned is my Issue:**

1. The CID not generating images over **HTTPS**. Page showing blank

**Note:** There is no issue whatsoever over HTTP

**Error on CID Service Logs**

This is the error on the CID Service but i am not sure if this has any
relation.

> ImageTransformationManager - Caught error
> 'TransformationException:Image format text/html is not supported'
> whilst transforming image, pathInfo=
> '/scale/1024x633/devdxa-us.ccccc.com/media/solution_tcm162-91770.png'
> com.sdl.context.image.api.exception.TransformationException: Image
> format text/html is not supported at
> com.sdl.context.image.transformation.processors.DefaultImageTransformationProcessor.processTransformation(DefaultImageTransformationProcessor.java:90)

**Detailed Logs**
2020-07-07 02:17:31,167 DEBUG [http-nio2-9188-exec-4] AmbientDataContext - Setting current ambient data context: com.tridion.ambientdata.web.WebContext
2020-07-07 02:17:31,167 DEBUG [http-nio2-9188-exec-4] AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter - Creating new session.
2020-07-07 02:17:31,205 DEBUG [http-nio2-9188-exec-4] AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter - Fetching ClaimStore stored in session :7B3507E07A80567AD7B81536EA269CBA
2020-07-07 02:17:31,206 DEBUG [http-nio2-9188-exec-4] AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter - Creating new ClaimStore
2020-07-07 02:17:31,208 DEBUG [http-nio2-9188-exec-4] DefaultClaimStore - put: uri=taf:response:cookie:generation, true
2020-07-07 02:17:31,209 DEBUG [http-nio2-9188-exec-4] WebContext - setCurrentClaimStore: com.tridion.ambientdata.claimstore.JavaClaimStore@67b086c5, thread: http-nio2-9188-exec-4
2020-07-07 02:17:31,209 DEBUG [http-nio2-9188-exec-4] DefaultClaimStore - put: uri=taf:request:uri, /cid/scale/1024x512/testdxa-us.nnnnnn.com/media/3-home-banner-desktop-Apr-19-Promo_tcm162-88634.jpg
2020-07-07 02:17:31,209 DEBUG [http-nio2-9188-exec-4] DefaultClaimStore - put: uri=taf:request:full_url, http://testdep1.nnnnnn-web.com:9188/cid/scale/1024x512/testdxa-us.nnnnnn.com/media/3-home-banner-desktop-Apr-19-Promo_tcm162-88634.jpg
2020-07-07 02:17:31,210 DEBUG [http-nio2-9188-exec-4] DefaultClaimStore - put: uri=taf:request:headers, {sec-fetch-mode=[Ljava.lang.String;@76ee1705, referer=[Ljava.lang.String;@7b65d0f, sec-fetch-site=[Ljava.lang.String;@50b84b4c, accept-language=[Ljava.lang.String;@501c68e0, x-forwarded-proto=[Ljava.lang.String;@564c1bd9, cookie=[Ljava.lang.String;@63277a3a, x-forwarded-port=[Ljava.lang.String;@7157af39, x-forwarded-for=[Ljava.lang.String;@423f929b, authorization=[Ljava.lang.String;@741bdbd6, x-amzn-trace-id=[Ljava.lang.String;@2c3599c5, host=[Ljava.lang.String;@60d7d51d, connection=[Ljava.lang.String;@5ec228d6, accept-encoding=[Ljava.lang.String;@742d8db3, sec-fetch-dest=[Ljava.lang.String;@7456c942, user-agent=[Ljava.lang.String;@2a7795e8}
2020-07-07 02:17:31,211 DEBUG [http-nio2-9188-exec-4] DefaultClaimStore - put: uri=taf:request:parameters, {CONTENT_LENGTH=[Ljava.lang.String;@65bc9ce8, QUERY_STRING=[Ljava.lang.String;@7de4d5f9, CONTENT_TYPE=[Ljava.lang.String;@3fba0fde, PATH_INFO=[Ljava.lang.String;@29741514}
2020-07-07 02:17:31,213 DEBUG [http-nio2-9188-exec-4] DefaultClaimStore - put: uri=taf:server:variables, {SERVER_PORT=9188, REMOTE_HOST=fe80:0:0:0:750a:9a16:62a:682%3, SERVER_PROTOCOL=HTTP/1.1, DOCUMENT_ROOT=C:\Windows\Temp\tomcat-docbase.5782942233258056690.9188, REQUEST_METHOD=GET, SCRIPT_NAME=/cid/scale/1024x512/testdxa-us.nnnnnn.com/media/3-home-banner-desktop-Apr-19-Promo_tcm162-88634.jpg, REMOTE_ADDR=fe80:0:0:0:750a:9a16:62a:682%3, SECURE=false, PATH_TRANSLATED=null, SERVER_NAME=testdep1.nnnnnn-web.com, AUTH_TYPE=null, REMOTE_USER=null}
2020-07-07 02:17:31,213 DEBUG [http-nio2-9188-exec-4] DefaultClaimStore - put: uri=taf:request:cookies, {ASP.NET_SessionId=jxt2lo52z522yg50lhf5o44p, _vis_opt_test_cookie=1, _vis_opt_exp_550_goal_1=1, _ngSupportStartTime=%7B%22date%22%3A%222020-06-26T11%3A18%3A19.555Z%22%2C%22surveySeen%22%3Afalse%2C%22startURL%22%3A%22https%253A%252F%252Fwww.nnnnnn.com%252Fsupport%252F%22%2C%22startDate%22%3A%222020-06-26T11%3A18%3A19.555Z%22%7D, TAFSessionId=tridion_f56df41f-b84e-4684-9f84-763b968c9f11, oc_dw_dnt=1, _vis_opt_s=43%7C, _vwo_uuid_348=DB3EA3E6F8477A909E186CC135DE44080, oc___cfduid=d335491cefeb6430ae77369205aaa98341593518630, hide_opIn_modal=1, oc___cq_dnt=1, _gid=GA1.2.1331472272.1594084063, _uetvid=3d7b642d-76c0-8a6d-9c31-b3c13057b50b, oc_dwsid=qBdPdTx7G3HOs2SlzMXMQU5jZQ39qAO02olpKAQWa1gSaognsBM4azD2EAVarSakulIEl_6i8usw0IXkEWCv7A%3d%3d, _vis_opt_exp_348_combi=2, oc_session_timeout=1594085864, _uetsid=edb4fbbc-b330-773d-a022-717baf5cc5c5, oc_dwanonymous_6f248c284c35e3147d0c22d9f042bb03=cdiPPTi98KbgvahRwfp0UxQA4t, oc_dwsecuretoken_6f248c284c35e3147d0c22d9f042bb03=H9uvREYTGCzuSyo1MpCjxWphExp6uvrvGA%3d%3d, _vis_opt_exp_348_combi_choose=2}
2020-07-07 02:17:31,215 INFO  [http-nio2-9188-exec-4] AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter - Requested by IP: /fe80:0:0:0:750a:9a16:62a:682%3
2020-07-07 02:17:31,215 DEBUG [http-nio2-9188-exec-4] AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter - Validating request.
2020-07-07 02:17:31,219 DEBUG [http-nio2-9188-exec-4] DefaultClaimStore - put: uri=taf:claim:contentdelivery:webservice:client:client_id, cduser
2020-07-07 02:17:31,219 DEBUG [http-nio2-9188-exec-4] DefaultClaimStore - put: uri=taf:claim:contentdelivery:webservice:client:Role, cd
2020-07-07 02:17:31,219 DEBUG [http-nio2-9188-exec-4] DefaultClaimStore - put: uri=taf:claim:contentdelivery:webservice:client:FirstName, CD
2020-07-07 02:17:31,219 DEBUG [http-nio2-9188-exec-4] DefaultClaimStore - put: uri=taf:claim:contentdelivery:webservice:client:AllowedCookieForwarding, true
2020-07-07 02:17:31,219 DEBUG [http-nio2-9188-exec-4] DefaultClaimStore - put: uri=taf:claim:contentdelivery:webservice:client:LastName, User
2020-07-07 02:17:31,219 DEBUG [http-nio2-9188-exec-4] DefaultClaimStore - put: uri=taf:claim:contentdelivery:webservice:client:expiresOn, 1594088548911
2020-07-07 02:17:31,219 DEBUG [http-nio2-9188-exec-4] DefaultClaimStore - put: uri=taf:claim:contentdelivery:webservice:client:digest, JYHnlQiIeBwF_qSxTnTRBboSJR3R7T5-M2_xJ4kfOfE=
2020-07-07 02:17:31,219 DEBUG [http-nio2-9188-exec-4] AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter - Request is validated.
2020-07-07 02:17:31,219 DEBUG [http-nio2-9188-exec-4] AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter - Processing claim cookies.
2020-07-07 02:17:31,219 DEBUG [http-nio2-9188-exec-4] AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter - Processing cookie claims.
2020-07-07 02:17:31,219 DEBUG [http-nio2-9188-exec-4] AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter - Cookie forwarding is enabled: false
2020-07-07 02:17:31,219 DEBUG [http-nio2-9188-exec-4] AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter - Processing Session Id and Tracking Id.
2020-07-07 02:17:31,220 DEBUG [http-nio2-9188-exec-4] DefaultClaimStore - put: uri=taf:session:id, tridion_f56df41f-b84e-4684-9f84-763b968c9f11
2020-07-07 02:17:31,220 DEBUG [http-nio2-9188-exec-4] DefaultClaimStore - put: uri=taf:tracking:id, tridion_8728b69c-a5ed-402d-8e9c-c86471a249fa
2020-07-07 02:17:31,220 DEBUG [http-nio2-9188-exec-4] DefaultClaimStore - put: uri=taf:session:attributes, {}
2020-07-07 02:17:31,220 DEBUG [http-nio2-9188-exec-4] AmbientDataServletFilter - Dispatching onRequestStart event
2020-07-07 02:17:31,221 DEBUG [http-nio2-9188-exec-4] ReadWriteFilter - Evaluating GET request: http://testdep1.nnnnnn-web.com:9188/cid/scale/1024x512/testdxa-us.nnnnnn.com/media/3-home-banner-desktop-Apr-19-Promo_tcm162-88634.jpg
2020-07-07 02:17:31,223 DEBUG [http-nio2-9188-exec-4] DefaultRulesEvaluator - Evaluating rule: com.sdl.web.readwrite.rules.PathRule@ecd3a9b for verb: GET and path: http://testdep1.nnnnnn-web.com:9188/cid/scale/1024x512/testdxa-us.nnnnnn.com/media/3-home-banner-desktop-Apr-19-Promo_tcm162-88634.jpg
2020-07-07 02:17:31,223 DEBUG [http-nio2-9188-exec-4] RequirementUtil - Requirements to match: [ClaimRequirement{claimName='taf:claim:contentdelivery:webservice:client:Role', claimValue='cd'}, ClaimRequirement{claimName='taf:claim:contentdelivery:webservice:client:Role', claimValue='cm'}]
2020-07-07 02:17:31,224 DEBUG [http-nio2-9188-exec-4] RequirementUtil - Claim value: cd required: cd condition met: true
2020-07-07 02:17:31,224 DEBUG [http-nio2-9188-exec-4] RequirementUtil - OR Operator, all claims met: true
2020-07-07 02:17:31,224 DEBUG [http-nio2-9188-exec-4] DefaultRulesEvaluator - Rule evaluation finished: DefaultRuleEvalResult{allowed=true, message=''}
2020-07-07 02:17:31,224 DEBUG [http-nio2-9188-exec-4] ReadWriteFilter - Rules were evaluated, access allowed to resource: GET: http://testdep1.nnnnnn-web.com:9188/cid/scale/1024x512/testdxa-us.nnnnnn.com/media/3-home-banner-desktop-Apr-19-Promo_tcm162-88634.jpg
2020-07-07 02:17:31,230 DEBUG [http-nio2-9188-exec-4] DispatcherServlet - GET "/cid/scale/1024x512/testdxa-us.nnnnnn.com/media/3-home-banner-desktop-Apr-19-Promo_tcm162-88634.jpg", parameters={}
2020-07-07 02:17:31,237 DEBUG [http-nio2-9188-exec-4] RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped to public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<byte[]> com.sdl.delivery.image.controller.ImageTransformerController.processRequest(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws java.io.IOException
2020-07-07 02:17:31,254 DEBUG [http-nio2-9188-exec-4] CachingTransformationProcessor - Checking whether key /scale/1024x512/testdxa-us.nnnnnn.com/media/3-home-banner-desktop-Apr-19-Promo_tcm162-88634.jpg is in image cache
2020-07-07 02:17:31,255 DEBUG [http-nio2-9188-exec-4] CachingTransformationProcessor - Adding image for key /scale/1024x512/testdxa-us.nnnnnn.com/media/3-home-banner-desktop-Apr-19-Promo_tcm162-88634.jpg to cache
2020-07-07 02:17:31,255 DEBUG [http-nio2-9188-exec-4] DefaultImageTransformationProcessor - URI to be transformed = '/scale/1024x512/testdxa-us.nnnnnn.com/media/3-home-banner-desktop-Apr-19-Promo_tcm162-88634.jpg'
2020-07-07 02:17:31,256 DEBUG [http-nio2-9188-exec-4] DimensionsArgument - Argument matches with 2 groups
2020-07-07 02:17:31,257 DEBUG [http-nio2-9188-exec-4] DimensionsArgument - Argument 1024 x 512
2020-07-07 02:17:31,259 DEBUG [http-nio2-9188-exec-4] DefaultImageTransformationProcessor - URL of image to be transformed='http://testdxa-us.nnnnnn.com/media/3-home-banner-desktop-Apr-19-Promo_tcm162-88634.jpg'
2020-07-07 02:17:31,259 DEBUG [http-nio2-9188-exec-4] ImageFactory - Creating UriImage from http://testdxa-us.nnnnnn.com/media/3-home-banner-desktop-Apr-19-Promo_tcm162-88634.jpg
2020-07-07 02:17:31,259 DEBUG [http-nio2-9188-exec-4] HttpImage - Creating UrlImage from string http://testdxa-us.nnnnnn.com/media/3-home-banner-desktop-Apr-19-Promo_tcm162-88634.jpg
2020-07-07 02:17:31,259 DEBUG [http-nio2-9188-exec-4] ContentTypeAcquirer - Derive content type from com.sdl.context.image.HttpImage@3f992b1c
2020-07-07 02:17:31,381 DEBUG [http-nio2-9188-exec-4] ContentTypeAcquirer - Content type from stream is text/html
2020-07-07 02:17:31,382 DEBUG [http-nio2-9188-exec-4] ContentTypeAcquirer - Derived content type text/html
2020-07-07 02:17:31,382 DEBUG [http-nio2-9188-exec-4] ContentTypeAcquirer - Extension text/html maps to content type htm
2020-07-07 02:17:31,383 WARN  [http-nio2-9188-exec-4] ImageTransformationManager - Caught error 'TransformationException:Image format text/html is not supported' whilst transforming image, pathInfo= '/scale/1024x512/testdxa-us.nnnnnn.com/media/3-home-banner-desktop-Apr-19-Promo_tcm162-88634.jpg'
com.sdl.context.image.api.exception.TransformationException: Image format text/html is not supported
at com.sdl.context.image.transformation.processors.DefaultImageTransformationProcessor.processTransformation(DefaultImageTransformationProcessor.java:90)
at com.sdl.context.image.transformation.processors.DefaultImageTransformationProcessor.processTransformation(DefaultImageTransformationProcessor.java:32)
at com.sdl.context.image.transformation.processors.CachingTransformationProcessor.processTransformation(CachingTransformationProcessor.java:112)
at com.sdl.context.image.transformation.processors.CachingTransformationProcessor.processTransformation(CachingTransformationProcessor.java:27)
at com.sdl.context.image.transformation.managers.ImageTransformationManager.processTransformation(ImageTransformationManager.java:90)
at com.sdl.delivery.image.controller.ImageTransformerController.processRequest(ImageTransformerController.java:65)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:88)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at com.sdl.web.readwrite.filter.ReadWriteFilter.doFilter(ReadWriteFilter.java:58)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at com.tridion.ambientdata.web.AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter.doFilter(AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter.java:298)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:114)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Nio2Endpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(Nio2Endpoint.java:1676)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.processSocket(AbstractEndpoint.java:1087)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Nio2Endpoint$Nio2SocketWrapper$2.completed(Nio2Endpoint.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Nio2Endpoint$Nio2SocketWrapper$2.completed(Nio2Endpoint.java:567)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:127)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Invoker$2.run(Invoker.java:219)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl.java:112)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)

Comment: Did you investigate the issue? Any errors in the logs?

Comment: In the log, I can see file extension shows png but Image format text/html which is something request content-type is getting wrong, Is that just that image not working or nothing works with https for cid images.  I would suggest enabling TRACE log level on webapp and cid service and trace the logs to see what is going on, also enable the access logs in the cid, so that you will know what request headers and format request comes to cid sevice.

Comment: Just to clarify to your query all images not working with CID. I am not able to render any image in the  page when on HTTPS

Comment: @sachin Jain do you still have this issue.

Comment: @sachinjain  can you please make sure CID whitelisting is enabled and also specific hostnames are added .